# 3d object overlay - augmented reality irrlicht + opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, matrix, augmented-reality, irrlicht

I am trying to develop an augmented reality program that overlays a 3d object on top of a marker. The model does not move along(proportionately) with the marker. Here are the list of things that I did

1) Using opencv: a) I used the solvepnp method to find rvecs and tvecs. b) I also used the rodrigues method to find the rotation matrix and appended the tvecs vector to get the projection matrix. c) Just for testing I made some points and lines and projected them to make a cube. This works perfectly fine and I am getting a good output.

2) Using irrlicht: a) I tried to place a 3d model(at position(0,0,0) and rotation(0,0,0)) with the camera feed running in the background. b) Using the rotation matrix found using rodrigues in opencv I calculated the pitch, yaw and roll values from this post("http://planning.cs.uiuc.edu/node103.html") and passed the value onto the rotation field. In the position field I passed the tvecs values. The tvecs values are tvecs[0], -tvecs[1], tvecs[2].

The model is moving in the correct directions but it is not moving proportionately. Meaning, if I move the marker 100 pixels in the x direction, the model only moves 20 pixels(the values 100 and 20 are not measured, I just took arbitrary values illustrate the example). Similarly for y axis and z axis. I do know I have to introduce another transformation matrix that maps the opencv camera coordinates to irrlicht camera coordinates and its a 4x4 matrix. But I do not know how to find it. Also the opencv's projections matrix [R|t] is a 3x4 matrix and it yields a 2d point that is to be projected. The 4x4 matrix mapping between opencv and irrlicht requires a 3d point(made homogeneous) to be fed into a 4x4 matrix. How do I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

The 4x4 matrix You are writing about seems to be `M=[ R|t; 0 1]`. `t` is 3x1 translation vector. To get the transformed coordinates `v'` of 4x1 ([x y z 1]^T) point `v` just do `v'=Mt`.

Your problem with scaling may be also caused by difference in units used for camera calibration in OpenCV and those used by the other library.